# JavaFX set MessageBox parameters

Tags: java, javafx, messagebox

I have a JavaFX program, it shows a simple MessageBox.

Box class:

```
public class Box extends Application implements Runnable{



    private DialogFX dialog1 = null;

    private String message = null;
    private String type = null;
    private String title = null;

    public Box(){}

    public void ShowBox(String ptype, String ptitle, String pmessage){

        type = ptype;
        title = ptitle;
        message = pmessage;


    }

    public void run() {
        Application.launch();
    }

    public void start(Stage stage){

         dialog1 = new DialogFX();
         dialog1.setTitleText(title);
         dialog1.setMessage(message);
         dialog1.showDialog();


    }
}
```

This class is using DialogFX library to create and show a simple message box. In the class there is a function called `ShowBox` which gets three parameters. These parameters is used to initialize the message box (title, type and message). In the `start()` method the new DialogFX object is created with needed parameters.

My problem is that when I create a new object of the `Box` class and set the three string parameter they are stay null in the `start()` method and the empty dialog box appears.

Example class to create a `Box` object:

```
public class MessageFrame {


    private static Box b = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b = new Box();
        b.ShowBox("ACCEPT", "Title", "Message here");
        b.run();

    }
}
```

I hope you can help me. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a JavaFX expert, but the problem is that actually two `Box` instances are created, one by you with:

```
b = new Box();
```

and one by the JavaFX framework when you call

```
Application.launch();
```

within your `run()` method. This latter instance will be your application (and the first created by you is not used at all) and it is not initialized properly (`ShowBox(...)` was not called on it).